# Bootstrap full grid-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on bootstrap and trying to make a `div` go full width (12 grids) on mobile.

```
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
```

I want it to be `9` on `md` but `12` on `xs`. How would one do that?

Comment: try `<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-12"></div>`

Comment: Usually It will be like `<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9"></div>`. The lg is for large screen and md for medium ones. For mobiles, it should be col-sm-12

Answer (score 3):

You need to use another class for mobiles. If they are `sm` or `xs`:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"></div>
```

If you use `col-sm-12`, it displays in 9 grid in desktop and full grid on devices that use `sm`. Also, if you need `100%` width, I guess that's the question about, you might consider not wrapping your element inside `.container*` class.

FYI, from the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

- `sm` - Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- `xs` - Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

Comment: Maybe it would be good to put the column classes from smallest to largest, as bootstrap is mobile first - as they use it like that in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed).

Comment: @Vucko Sure. But that doesn't matter. `<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"></div>` is same as `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9"></div>`. The CSS definition is what decides everything. `:)`

Comment: I know it doesn't matter, but let's say it's "best practise" :) (atleast for my and my OCD :D )

Comment: @Vucko Haven't seen that kind of "best practise", but yes, your reasoning is nice. Thanks. Will take into account. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you want 12 in xs then add this class also

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"></div>
```